# Is it possible to write "rem" as inline css?

Tags: html, css

`<img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="3rem">`

So I have this code and I tried to give it a width as an inline css. At first I wrote 3rem because I wanted it to be 48px but it turned out as 3px.

Then I wrote it as `<img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="48px">` and it turned out like I wanted to.

I kinda solved the problem but I wonder is it allows px only or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the [style attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but [the `width` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content-other.html#attr-dim-width) doesn't take a CSS value. It takes an integer (and the `px` you have is an error that gets ignored).

(Historical note: [HTML 4 supported a percentage there](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#Length) too.)

If you want to write inline CSS use the `style` attribute:

```
style="width: 3rem"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default inline css interpret the value in "px", but you can concatenate the value with other units, like that:

```
style={{ height: 55+'rem' }}
```